# Paperclip file name in validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, file, paperclip

Here is what I'm trying to do in the model:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => self.image_sizes, :whiny => false

validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'],
                                :message => I18n.t('paperclip.invalid_image_type', :file => self.photo.original_file_name)
```

I cant find the solution how should I get file name in `original_file_name`:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `photo_file_name' for #<Class:0xaafb004>):
```

or

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `photo' for #<Class:0xb303e7c>):
```

Comment: Can you post what error are you getting over here

Answer (score 1):

Problem is *self* is not the instance, but rather **Class**.

You can use the uploaded content-type as follows:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'],
                            :message => :inclusion
```

and then in your translation file, add

`activerecord.errors.models.<modelname>.attributes.photo.inclusion: "%{value} is not allowed"`

where *value* will be replaced with the uploaded content type

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was talking about file name, not about content type.

Comment: You may then consider modifying Paperclip to pass the original file name to the message interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `photo_file_name` instead of `photo.original_file_name`.

For more information on this, refer to [Method: Paperclip::Attachment#original_filename](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Attachment%3aoriginal_filename)

Hope it helps.

Comment: If it would be so easy, I wouldn't ask the question. So sorry, doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html

self.photo.url

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
self.photo.instance_read(:file_name)
```

For more information on `Paperclip::Attachment#instance_read`, refer to the docs [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Attachment%3ainstance_read).

Hope this helps.